# Java Spring (Page<Entity>.Map(new Converter))

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im trying to put the class that implements converter to Page

Class that implements Converter Class:

```
public class RoomEntityToReservationResponseConverter implements Converter<RoomEntity, ReservationResponse> {}
```

THEN THE 'MAP' GOES RED IN THE CODE BELOW.

Other Class to map the Class implements Converter:

```
Page<RoomEntity> roomEntityList = pageableRoomRepository.findAll(pageable);
return roomEntityList.map(new RoomEntityToReservationResponseConverter());
```

Comment: What is the type signature of the Page.map method, and what is the return type of the function your code snippet appears in? What actual error message does your compiler give you?

Comment: basically the Page<Entity>.map is looking for Function and im putting a method that return as converter. the error says,: (argument mismatch; RoomEntityToReservationResponseConverter cannot be converted to Function<? super RoomEntity,? extends R>)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Page.map` accept a function. Hence the compiler give you a compile error.

What should you do is to inject an instance of `RoomEntityToReservationResponseConverter`, then use it to convert your response (Here `RoomEntityToReservationResponseConverter` must be annotated so that the container know it should instantiate your converter. Typically put `@Component` to the class)

```
@Autowired
private RoomEntityToReservationResponseConverter converter;

...
Page<RoomEntity> roomEntityList = pageableRoomRepository.findAll(pageable);
return roomEntityList.map(converter::convert);
```

Comment: Can you answer my other post sir? Spring boot is so confusing to me. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172000/spring-boot-can-optional-class-be-like-list-class

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `converter::convert`. I'm migrating to spring boot  2 (from 1.5 to 2.1) and they changed the signature of map i.e. it no longer accepts `Convert` as a parameter but use `Function` instead. I started changing all concrete Converters to implement `Function`, which seemed pretty fishy at some point. I'm glad I saw your answer.

Comment: @YounesElOuarti Happy lambda coding ^^